# How to find document by _id in MongoDB's cursor and next and previous _id's?

Tags: mongodb

We have a big MongoDB collection, and request part of it by:

```
db.find({..some condition}).sort(...)
```

also, we have _id (=x2) of a document. Our goal is to define _id (x1, x3) of next and previous documents.

```
....
{_id: x1, something: 'text1'},
{_id: x2, something: 'text1'},
{_id: x3, something: 'text1'},
....
```

Comment: Are your _id's actually the Object Id?

Comment: What do you mean by "next and previous"? There aren't rows and `ObjectIds` are normally generated by a client, not by the server, so they aren't necessarily synchronized unless you only have **one** client doing all of the document insertions.

Comment: @WiredPrairie actually the `ObjectId` **would** be always increasing (monotonic) by insert, "regardless" of the client that inserted them. But that's not the point. Given a known matching document **after** a sort is applied, you cannot get to the document preceding it. Nothing to do but scan through, keeping the last document, until the wanted document is found. Unsorted, and by `ObjectId` this is easy, because the insertion order is maintained.

Comment: As the time is the first part of the ObjectID, the sort will not be determined by absolute inserts, but by clock time of the clients.